# Argon2 installation for xampp

Tags: php, xampp, typo3, typo3-9.x, macos-high-sierra

I have installed a TYPO3 version 9.5.24 on xampp 7.4.15 on my localhost.

The TYPO3 system is from a production system and uses argon2 hash system for the install tool password.

My problem is that I don't know how to install argon2 for xampp. Does anyone have a guide for the installation?

I'm currently working on a mac OS high sierra. I have installed argon2 on my mac using homebrew but i still can't log in to the install tool.

Comment: I have no idea about Xampp, but I can only recommend [DDEV](https://www.ddev.com/ddev-local/) to you. It creates fully fledged docker based development environments. Each environment can have it's own settings and features and of course Argon2 is supported out of the box. Among other CMS, TYPO3 is also supported. If you need help, there is a super nice and helpful channel on [TYPO3 Slack](https://typo3.slack.com/archives/C8TRNQ601).

Comment: Thank you i will definitely try that one!